# How can I transcribe a call recording with Twilio Voice?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-click-to-call

I am building an application that needs to make outbound calls to customers.
I need these calls recorded and transcribed.

I have been getting very confused on how to achieve this, but this is what I have so far in a NextJS API endpoint I have built to trigger a call:

```
import twilio from 'twilio'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
const twilioNumber = process.env.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER

interface OutBoundCall {
  to: string
}

export const POST = async (request: Request) => {
  const { to }: OutBoundCall = await request.json()
  if (!to) return NextResponse.json({ message: 'No to number provided' })
  try {
    const client = twilio(accountSid, authToken)
    client.calls
      .create({
        to: 'XXXXX', // <-- This is just my personal phone number for now whilst testing
        from: twilioNumber as string,
        twiml: `<Response><Dial><Number>${to}</Number></Dial></Response>`,
        record: true
      })
      .then(call => console.log(call.sid))
    return NextResponse.json({ message: `Call has been triggered to ${to}` })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log({ error })
    return NextResponse.json(error)
  }
}
```

This is currently calling my personal phone and then dialling the number I have passed in once it has connected to me.

I am finding if I add the `<Record transcribe="true" />` in the TwiML, it never actually records or transcribes. Adding the `record: true` to the `client/calls.create` method does work, but it does not accept a `transcribe` parameter.

How can I achieve this?

I have a feeling I am doing this wrong anyway, as in my call logs, it appears as 2 calls (one to me, and then one to the number I actually want to call), so I believe I'm being double charged.

If I am doing this wrong, how should I go about this?

What I actually want to happen in an ideal situation:

- A user clicks a "Call" button in the frontend
- A POST request is sent to either an endpoint of mine, or a Twilio one
- The number I want to speak to starts ringing through the users machine and just the one call is triggered direct from my frontend to the user

I did try using the `Device` component in my react frontend, but I could never get it working.

This is the code I was trying:

```
import { Device } from '@twilio/voice-sdk'

const makeCall = async () => {
  try {
    const device = new Device(
      'my-jwt-here' // (I can succesfully make JWTs)
    )

    const call = await device.connect({
      params: {
        To: 'XXXX', // The phone number I want to call
      }
    })
    console.log({ call })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log({ error })
  }
}

export const MakeACallPage = () => {
  return <button onClick={makeCall}>Make a call here</button>
}
```

All the docs I can find about making outbound calls all seem to be a simple version where the call simply speaks pre-defined words to the user and does not show how to make calls where 2 people can talk to one another.

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems Twilio doesn't support transcription of entire calls.

The `<Record>` verb can only record the caller. The verb [doesn't support nesting](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record#nesting-rules) so you can't have any other verbs running at the same time. `<Record>` is basically only useful for recording voicemail.

If you really want to transcribe entire calls, it seems you'll have to use another API to transcribe the recordings. [OpenAI](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/speech-to-text) is one option, among many.

As for your issue with the Voice JavaScript SDK, I'd suggest creating a separate question for that. I don't have the experience to help you with that one, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use Voice Intelligence to transcribe entire calls in real time or post-processing https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/intelligence/api

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35849423)